# Unwrapping long datatype in Swift Linux

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu, swift3, perfect

I'm trying to get a record from MongoDB which has a DateTime property. This property is ISODate but is received as a long data type (milliseconds since 1970) through the Perfect-MongoDB API.

The code looks like this:

```
if var something = dictionary["Something"] as? [String:Any], var intDate = something["$date"] as? Int64
{
 let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(intDate/1000))
}
```

This code is working fine in Mac OSX. However in Linux, `created["$date"] as? Int64` is always `nil`.

I've tried a couple of things, including using `Double` and `NSNumber` instead of Int64 but it is still `nil`.

Any ideas on how I can access this number? I need to convert it to a readable date, and the way I'm doing this is through `TimeInterval()` which needs a Double value for seconds after 1970, so it needs to be divisible by 1000 and  convertible to Double during that step.

Edit: This is the NSNumber code where `intDate` is still `nil` and thus doesn't fall through the `let date` line. `something` is not nil

```
if var something = dictionary["Something"] as? [String:Any], var intDate = something["$date"] as? NSNumber
{
  let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(NSDecimalNumber(decimal:intDate.decimalValue/1000).doubleValue))
}
```

Edit 2: Sample Dictionary for this case:

```
var dictionary : [String:Any] = ["SomethingElse":"SomeOtherData","Something":["$date": 1507710414599]]
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried with NSNumber? That should work.

Comment: @MartinR added my code for that one in my edit

Comment: Try `as? Int` ...

Comment: Can you add a (preferably minimal) `dictionary` to your code which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @MartinR I added one in, thanks

Comment: Casting to Int works in the IBM Swift 3 Sandbox (which runs on Linux as well): https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59ddd7dc5457787c21474941.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah soo I found out when I tried to run my dictionary that that actually worked. I was building through source control and I didn't realize there was a little hiccup when I made changes using Int the last time. So sorry about that. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is only limited conversion between integer types and `NSNumber` in Swift on Linux, so you have to cast to the exact type,
which is `Int` in this case:

```
let dictionary : [String: Any] = ["SomethingElse":"SomeOtherData","Something":["$date": 1507710414599]]

if let something = dictionary["Something"] as? [String:Any],
    let numDate = something["$date"] as? Int {

    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(numDate)/1000)
    print("Date:", date)
}
```

Comment: Isn't `Int` just a typealias for `Int64` on 64-bit platforms(which is majority now, i guess)?

Comment: @user28434: `Int` has the same size as Int64 (or Int32 on a 32-bit platform). But is is a different type. You can verify that `let y: Int64 = Int(123)` does not compile.

Comment: Ok, got it. I thought code in answer is almost same as in question.